# Get module of method caller

Tags: python, introspection, pytest

Up to now we use this to get the module of the method caller:

```
frame=inspect.currentframe().f_back
module=inspect.getmodule(frame.f_code)
```

It works well, except in py.test TestCases.

Py.test returns the file name as module name.

Our test code layout:

```
foomodule/lib/examplecode.py
foomodule/tests/test_examplecode.py
```

If called in `examplecode.py` the result is *'foomodule'*. But called in `test_examplecode.py` it returns *'test_examplecode'*.

Answer (score 0):

py.test does work with the AST of the modules under test so it could possibly be changing this value (wrongly?).  If so this is probably a bug.

Could you please show an example of a test where this fails?  E.g. to clarify if the inspect code is running as the test function or is it the code under test?

Could you also indicate any presence of `__init__.py` files as this might help make it clear what the packages and modules are.

Having said that using the stack and inspect in this way is usually frowned upon.